# How can I change the direction of labels?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, direction

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="panel-body" style="direction: rtl;">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="LX7HWby1aME0NLMslEr2AHkxTRGBK7pRDYKTrh9P">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="content" class="col-md-4 control-label">Content</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="content" rows="4" class="form-control" cols="50" name="content"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

If you run code snippet above in full size screen, you will see titles are in the left side, and inputs are in the right side *(next to each other)*

My website supports multi languages, also as you know, some languages are `rtl` direction. So I need to change the position of inputs and titles together. I mean I need to adjust inputs in the right side and titles in the left side *(on the contrary of current structure)* by adding some CSS code.

How can I do that?

---

#### Current UI:

[image]

#### Expected UI: *(by using only CSS, not changing HTML)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use the `:lang()` css selector with the rtl languages.

For example with arabic, you can use:

```
:lang(ar) .form-group label{ 
    /* You can put here all the desired properties */
}
```

You can read more about it in **[CSS-Tricks's :lang() selector tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/lang/)**, but you have to pay attention to its browser compatibility.

Comment: you know, `float: right;` doesn't change the position of titles

Comment: @MartinAJ, it was just an example.

Comment: I see, but look, I can select the expected element, I don't know how can I change its position. neither `float` nor `direction` properties won't work.

Comment: From what I see in your code you are using bootstrap, you need to tag your question with `bootstrap` to get more help and see how to do it with bootstrap, because using only CSS may not be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pull-right` class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-

BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="panel-body" style="direction: rtl;">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="LX7HWby1aME0NLMslEr2AHkxTRGBK7pRDYKTrh9P">
    <div class="form-group">

      <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label  pull-right" style="text-align:left" >Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label pull-right " style="text-align:left">E-Mail Address</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="content" class="col-md-2 control-label pull-right " style="text-align:left">Content</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <textarea id="content" rows="4" class="form-control" cols="50" name="content"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bootstrap-rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl) to do the job for you.

> Bootstrap RTL provides simple yet robust right-to-left capability for
>   Bootstrap 3, by employing new theming feature of it. Simply put its
>   CSS after bootstrap's original CSS, to the pages designed by Bootstrap
>   3. It works just like an extension on top of the original Bootstrap

You can either include it from your server or use a CDN. For a CDN example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.css" />
```